# Is there a way to view or set custom Microsoft Word shortcuts for Mac OS when working in Windows?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2011

I'm using a Microsoft Word 2010 (Windows version) to make some templates that contain custom shortcuts for styles, macros, etc. The templates will also be used by coworkers using Word 2011 on OS X. Some of the shortcuts that I've set up on Windows don't work on OS X; they show up in the keyboard shortcuts dialog without modifier keys (so, e.g., a shortcut shows up as `1` instead of `Alt+Ctrl+1`). If I open the templates in OS X, I can add shortcuts, but again, most modifiers aren't shown when I reopen the file on Windows (`Ctrl+Option+1` becomes `1`). In both cases, the shortcuts are still in the file and are available when I'm using the "correct" operating system.

Problem is, I don't have regular access to a Mac. Is there a way to view (and preferably change) the Mac keyboard shortcuts from Windows?

UPDATE: I tried using the VBA KeyBind object to view the shortcuts. I could view the bound command (the command property), but trying to view the actual bound keys through the keyString property didn't work. On Windows, I can view the Windows bound keys, but trying to view the OS X bound keys raises an invalid parameter exception. The reverse is true on OS X: I can view the OS X bound keys, but trying to view the Windows bound keys raises an exception.

I haven't tried adding or modifying the key bindings through VBA yet (and don't plan to until I have some way to view them).

Comment: I'd prefer a GUI-based solution, but VBA works for me, too.